# Can't control BeagleBone Green's LEDs on Debian 8.6

Tags: javascript, linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to use usr LEDs on BeagleBone Green Wireless on Debian 8.6 (default image from http://beagleboard.org/green with kernel `4.4.26-ti-r59`) for my own debug purposes, but some script make it impossible. It is caused most likely by a JS script (after uninstalling nodejs leds stopped beating, but JS is crucial for me).

I've already tried to switch mode of led blink to none:

```
# cd /sys/class/leds/beaglebone\:green\:usr0
# echo none > trigger
# cat trigger
[none] rc-feedback kbd-scrollock ...
```

and to control brightness:

```
# echo 0 > brightness 
# cat brightness 
0
# echo 255 > brightness 
# cat brightness 
0
# cat brightness 
1
```

As you can see - value of brightness is simply being overwritten by another program (script) running in loop. Does anyone have an idea which script may cause this situation?